# How to put total of table in formula dax?

Tags: excel, dax

Currently, I am using this Dax formula.

=DIVIDE ( [Sum of Sales_RM], 4600, 0 )

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlIHR.png)

How I change 4600 hard code to total Sum of Table Sales_RM?

Since 4600 is not my final total, so I cannot use this formula, hope someone can guide me.

Comment: haven't , I already display error message in your comment